# What does « porté au pardon » mean?

Tags: sens, prépositions, verbes

A [question I asked on the Latin Stack Exchange site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/what-is-the-correct-etymology-of-ign%C5%8Dsc%C5%8D-pardon) led to a French text, the *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine* by Alfred Ernout and Antoine Meillet. The relevant passage uses the gloss « porté au pardon » to explain the meaning of a Latin phrase. But unfortunately, I don't understand what the French means.

Here is the sentence (you can see more of the passage in the linked Latin SE post):

> *Ignōscēns sīs* ne saurait donc se dire dans le sens de « pardonne » : quand Térence dit *animus ignoscentior*, Heaut. 635, il l'emploie comme adjectif pour marquer une disposition de l'esprit avec le sens de « porté au pardon ».

I know that "porté" is the past participle of *porter,* and the noun *pardon* means pretty much the same thing here as the English noun. I'm having trouble with the sense of *porter* here and the meaning of the prepositional phrase. The [TLFi entry for *porter*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter) is very long; I tried to look for an example that seemed similar, but I couldn't find one.

Would it be correct to translate « porté au pardon » as "inclined to give pardon"? Or does it mean instead something like "brought to give pardon"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The meaning is indeed "inclined to give pardon".

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/port%C3%A9/1)

> **II. −** Adjectif
>   ...
>   **B. −** [Corresp. à porter 1re Section II]
>   ...
>   **4.** *Au fig.* [En parlant d'une pers.] Qui a de l'inclinaison, de la disposition pour.
>   ...
>   **b)** [En parlant d'une pers. ou de son esprit]
>   **α)** **Porté à** + subst. exprimant une action ou un état/+ inf. Qui manifeste une forte disposition, un fort penchant pour quelque chose. Synon. *enclin à. Porté à l'action, à l'amour, à l'indulgence, au mal, au scepticisme; esprit porté à l'étude; porté à boire, à croire que. Vous paraissez, au contraire, porté à l'apoplexie* (Flaub., *Mme Bovary*, t.2, 1857, p.21). *À la sainte messe, prendre garde à certains mots que je suis porté à mal prononcer* (Dupanloup, *Journal*, 1866, p.272). *Parmi les Belges Georges Minne, grave et recueilli, est trop souvent porté à la stylisation* (*Arts et litt.*, 1936, p.18-5).

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't think to look for a separate entry for "porté"